# Addthis change url - query parameter

Tags: addthis

I have a url something like this local.ad.company.com/Web... In this i want to remove the ad.company.com when addthis buttons are clicked. Please help.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Basically without any javascript involved you can do something like this [(source)](http://www.addthis.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=20172)

```
<a href="http://www.addthis.com/bookmark.php" 
    class="addthis_button"
    addthis:url="http://example.com"
    addthis:title="An Example Title"
    addthis:description="An Example Description"></a>
```

AddThis recommends using its [Sharing API](http://www.addthis.com/help/client-api#configuration-sharing) and personally I think it's the best way of implementing it.